# Array ID is passed as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this JavaScript `array` in which I made a key-value pair and wanted to pass both keys and values separately like this:

My array:

```
var str = {
    "attacker": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".movie").append(data)
        }
    }),
    "defender": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
        }
    }),
    "midfielder": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
        }
    }),
    "goalkeeper": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
        }
    })
}
```

Now passing keys and value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i++) {
    var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
    var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;
    group.add(new Element(Object.keys(str), str[i], new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i * incrementAngle * (Math.PI / 180.0), 0)));
    startRadians += incrementRadians;
}
scene.add(group);
```

I used str.id to get the key but it is passing as undefined can someone tell how to pass he key only.

Comment: *"I made this javascript array"* That's not an array. That's an *object*. (Arrays are *also* objects, but that's a non-array object.)

Comment: Even if you get the keys, the idea to assign `$.ajax` return values to properties is wrong. You'll get deferreds assigned to them, not the requested values.

Comment: Check the answer. You need to use Object.keys() so as to get the key array of JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Object.keys` for JSON objects like

```js
var str = {
    "attacker": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".movie").append(data)
        }
    }),
    "defender": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
        }
    }),
    "midfielder": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
        }
    }),
    "goalkeeper": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data)
        }
    })
};

var allKeys = Object.keys(str);
console.log(allKeys[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: I is showing id but as 1,2,3,attacker don't know where that 1,2,3 comed from

Comment: What do you expect the output @RaghavPatnecha

Comment: Did you see that group.add line i added in the code. I want to send only one key at time

Comment: Ok then i have edited my answer check it. You can use var allKeys = Object.keys(str); and then access key at particular index as in console.log

Comment: works for me but why everybody is saying thats a wrong idea to put ajax in value

Comment: Where did i used the word iterate. I asked him to access the key by index value.

Answer (score 0):

That is an object, not array.

A simple `for ... in` will help:

```
for (key in str)
    group.add( new Element( key, str[key], new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0), 0) ) );
```

Comment: Its an object, not array, @RaghavPatnecha you're using the wrong type of loop. Read the actual answer.

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha object.keys is the wrong idea - and bad code. That is not how you're supposed to iterate through an object.